# how to add 'https://jitpack.io library to android studio version bumble bee?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

In last versions of android studio we can simply add the library `https://jitpack.io` to the `gradle` file (module project) easily but in the newest update (`android-studio-bumble-bee`), the structure of this file has been changed and I don't know how to add this library.

Answer (score 23):

For **Kotlin DSL** inside *settings.gradle.kts* file you can use `setUrl()` just like this.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           setUrl("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @A. baladastian, please see if this answer your needs and, if so, check it as accepted to signal users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it in your `settings.gradle` the following way:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // add it like this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can added in the project settings look for settings gradle hope it helps[image: look the screenshot]

Comment: not working in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

Comment: @JayeshDankhara are you able to find any solution?

Comment: This is a terrible way to answer, no text and an unreadable image

Comment: it was just to show him where lol     .I.  !! you can literally zoom in and out .... people just want everything chewed....

Answer (score -1):

On Module level build.gradle (not app level)

```
repositories{
    maven { url = "https://jitpack.io"}
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    
}
```